# How can I make plots with TikZ which look like the new Mathematica 9 plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

The new Mathematica 9 is out! I would love to know how to make similar plots to the [one's advertized](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/), particularly the following:

[image: plot with lines from x-axis each point]
**and** 
[image: a plot with changing colors after specific point]

Here is a simple plot to get started.

```
%& -shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
3.045784        3.415896
3.405784        4.025693
3.785784        4.522530
4.125784        5.538449
4.485784        6.704992
4.805784        6.978939
5.145784        7.113496
5.425784        8.916397
6.065784        9.487712
6.365784        10.876397
6.685784        10.693497
7.025784        11.364131
7.345784        11.442530
7.665784        12.582530
8.005784        13.125693
8.225784        13.738450
8.585784        14.247891
8.865784        14.982530
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=0.4cm]

  \def\xmin{3}
  \def\xmax{9.2}
  \def\ymin{2}
  \def\ymax{15.5}

  % grid
  \draw[style=help lines, ystep=2, xstep=1] (\xmin,\ymin) grid
  (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) node[above] {$y$};

  % xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in {3,4,...,9}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {2,4,...,14}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};

  % plot the data from the file data.dat
  % smooth the curve and mark the data point with a dot
  \draw[color=blue] plot[smooth,mark=*,mark size=1pt] file {data.dat}
   node [right] {data};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: simple plot example]

Comment: Congrats by the way for a nice graph without `pgfplots` I was looking for the start of the axis environment :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a way of doing this with PGFPlots: The first plot is simply a `ycomb` plot, and the second I would draw using separate plots for the areas (with a trailing `\closedcycle` to get the filling right) and the lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
3.045784        3.415896
3.405784        4.025693
3.785784        4.522530
4.125784        5.538449
4.485784        6.704992
4.805784        6.978939
5.145784        7.113496
5.425784        8.916397
6.065784        9.487712
6.365784        10.876397
6.685784        10.693497
7.025784        11.364131
7.345784        11.442530
7.665784        12.582530
8.005784        13.125693
8.225784        13.738450
8.585784        14.247891
8.865784        14.982530
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.5,
    width=10cm,
    height=5cm
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!10},
]
\addplot [ycomb, red, very thick, mark=*, mark options={red!60!black}] table {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!10},
    enlarge x limits=false
]
\addplot [draw=none, fill=orange!40!yellow] table {data.dat} \closedcycle;
\addplot [draw=gray, very thick] table {data.dat};

\addplot [draw=none, fill=red!60] table [
    x expr=\thisrowno{0}+8.865784-3.045784,
    y expr=\thisrowno{1}+14.982530-3.415896
] {data.dat} \closedcycle;
\addplot [draw=red!70!black, very thick] table [
    x expr=\thisrowno{0}+8.865784-3.045784,
    y expr=\thisrowno{1}+14.982530-3.415896
] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22):

Aha, Jake was way faster.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
axis background/.style={shade,top color=gray!20,bottom color=white},
]
\addplot[ycomb,mark=*,mark color=black,domain=2:10,samples=70] {rnd+(x)^0.3333};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymax=7,
axis background/.style={shade,top color=gray!20,bottom color=white},
]
\addplot[fill=orange,no marks,samples=500,domain=1.5:10] {rnd+ln(x)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=brown,no marks,samples=100,domain=10:12] {0.5*rnd+ln(x)} \closedcycle;
\draw node[append after command={ (a) -| (axis cs:11,2)}] (a) at (axis cs:6,4) {Global Filtering!};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

To begin with,  I would recommend moving your example to use `pgfplots`, and then work it out.

$1000 cheaper you get this (code below)[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
3.045784        3.415896
3.405784        4.025693
3.785784        4.522530
4.125784        5.538449
4.485784        6.704992
4.805784        6.978939
5.145784        7.113496
5.425784        8.916397
6.065784        9.487712
6.365784        10.876397
6.685784        10.693497
7.025784        11.364131
7.345784        11.442530
7.665784        12.582530
8.005784        13.125693
8.225784        13.738450
8.585784        14.247891
8.865784        14.982530
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=0.4cm]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[ycomb] table {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=0.4cm]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[fill=orange, opacity=0.5,mark=none] table {data.dat} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```