# LaTeX and Mathematica plot with same font/style

Tags: plot, psfrag, wolfram-mathematica

I know there are a couple of questions with answers to this but none of them seems to work for me so I ask here. Some basic facts:

I have
1. Mac OSX 
2. Very limited knowledge in Terminal (so things like `--shell escape` mean zero to me)
3. TeXShop
4. Mathematica 9

I would like to plot with Mathematica but use LaTeX on the plot with the same font as in the main TeX-file. I've heard some about PStools, PSfrag and so on but don't know how to install them or apply them. It would be nice with a simple line of code to do everything but with very little Terminal/command line.

EXAMPLE: 
As suggested in threads elsewhere I do this in Mathematica 9

```
plot = Plot[Sin[Exp[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"e", "s"}]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "plot.eps", plot]
```

And then I make a new LaTeX document with the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\psfragfig{plot}{%
    \psfrag{e}{$\epsilon$}
    \psfrag{s}{$\Sigma$}}  
\end{document}
```

The file plot.eps is the one I exported from Mathematica 9. 
The result is unfortunately not good because there's only "e" and "s" instead of $\epsilon$ and $\Sigma$ see figure! [image]

Comment: Can you export your data out of mathematica?

Comment: @percusse Yes, the file plot.eps is from Mathematica

Comment: See MaTeX, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica/76943#76943 or http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html

Comment: No I mean the actual numbers to be plotted. Then you can plot it in `pgfplots` without any problems (and no terminal)

Comment: @percusse Oh I see, that sounds nice. But what if the plot is not of an analytic function but rather of some unknown data, does that matter? How would you do it with pgfplots? Can one use LaTeX for the labels in that case?

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate --- can you make the `eps` file available for download and add a link here?

Comment: Check out some examples http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84856/how-can-i-make-plots-with-tikz-which-look-like-the-new-mathematica-9-plots ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you plot it directly with `pgfplots`?

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
          xlabel=$\epsilon$,ylabel=$\Sigma$,
          every axis y label/.style=
                    {at={(axis cs:0,1.3)},anchor=south},
          every axis x label/.style={
                    at={(axis cs: 3.5,0)},anchor=west},
          xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,ymin=-1.3,ymax=1.3]
      \addplot[red,samples=1000,domain=-pi:pi] {sin(deg(exp(x)))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Is there a simple way to a similar thing with plotting data from Mathematica 9? Suppose I plot a numerical integration in Mathematica 9 to which there is no analytical function, just data. How can one plot that with `pgfplots`? Thanks for your solution bro.

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate certainly there is. You have to provide a sample data though. There are lot of such examples in `pgfplots` manual. You can access the manual at www.texdoc.net or  by running `texdoc pgfplots` in terminal of your computer.

Comment: So I should save something like a `data = Table[]` in M9?

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate Please consult the pgfplots manual for some examples of data formats.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you use the same font in Mathematica and in your article? You would simply declare in the plot function of Mathematica that you want the labels to be in the same font and size of the article. Export the plot in pdf format and use LaTeX the command in your LaTeX file:

> ```
> \begin{figure}
>   \ifpdf
>    \pdfximage width \columnwidth{plotname.pdf}
>    \pdfrefximage \pdflastximage
>   \else
>    \includegraphics{plotname.png}
>   \fi
> \end{figure}
> ```

Comment: With "font" I mean the exact way/font as in my LaTeX file.

Comment: @shutupandcalculate: have you tried? What difference do you see? If it is a size question, maybe you might want to increase (decrease) the font size in Mathematica. Mathematica is able to use all the available fonts on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small package called [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) that makes it easy to generate figure labels for Mathematica graphics using LaTeX.  A short introduction, including instructions on how to match up font styles, is available in this other StackExchange post:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76943/12